# Override a node template and its associated translation

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

I'm trying to understand how to override a node template in order to "catch" also all the associated node translations.

Let's say I have a `node/12` in English and its translation is `node/13`. To override in the same way both nodes I have to create `templates/node--12.tpl.php` and `templates/node--13.tpl.php` inside my theme folder.

Is there a way to avoid this, since the customisations I plan to implement on the node and its translation are the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a content type for the translations and use that content-type node template. `node--CONTENTTYPENAME.tpl.php`. 
so you don't need to update it one by one with the node ID.